Error reading channel data (7) - Downloading large files via league/sftp
Using:

laravel/framework@v11.2.0
laravel/sail@v1.29.1
league/filesystem@3.27.0
league/flysystem-sftp-v3@3.26.0

I'm trying to use the SFTP filesystem driver to download files to the local filesystem from remote, but on large files that take over a minute to download, I get kicked out with this error:

The code referenced above on line 55 is pretty simple, it's within a command I have for testing where I select which files to download then attempt to fetch them within a task action:
Storage::disk('local')->writeStream(
    "sftp/{$localFilename}",
    Storage::disk('sftp')->readStream($remoteFilePath)
);

I've also tried passing in a variable for reference (thinking initializing it outside of the writeStream would help, it didn't), using ->get() instead of ->readStream() to try and load the whole thing into memory, neither of those approaches worked either.
Then my configuration for the sftp disk in config/filesystems.php looks like this currently:
'sftp' => [
    'driver' => 'sftp',
    'host' => env('SFTP_HOST'),
    'username' => env('SFTP_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('SFTP_PASSWORD'),
    // 'privateKey' => env('SFTP_PRIVATE_KEY'),
    // 'passphrase' => env('SFTP_PASSPHRASE'),
    // 'visibility' => 'private', // `private` = 0600, `public` = 0644
    // 'directory_visibility' => 'private', // `private` = 0700, `public` = 0755
    // 'hostFingerprint' => env('SFTP_HOST_FINGERPRINT'),
    // 'maxTries' => 4,
    // 'passphrase' => env('SFTP_PASSPHRASE'),
    // 'port' => env('SFTP_PORT', 22),
    // 'root' => env('SFTP_ROOT', ''),
    // 'timeout' => 30,
    // 'useAgent' => true,
],

I've tried adjusting the timeout and useAgent settings, but that didn't work either.
Since I'm using Sail, I was able to find some vaguely related SSH connection articles online that suggested adding a ServerAliveInterval to my ssh_config file, so I linked this in my docker-compose.yml under the laravel.test service:
volumes:
    - '.:/var/www/html'
    - './docker/ssh_config:/etc/ssh/ssh_config'

where docker/ssh_config looks like this:
Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf

Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    ServerAliveInterval 300

Then I rebuilt and started the container, but that didn't work either.
I'm able to download this file with no problem either via scp or using a client like FileZilla, so I'm not really sure what else I can do to resolve this.
Does anyone have any ideas, or is there a configuration for this package or Docker container that I'm missing?

Did you try with the SSH2 extension (as shown here)?

// timeout (optional, default: 10) check here. PS:  how much timeout have you put?

@francisco I've tried all the way up to 3600 for the timeout with no luck. @ Olivier same issue

@Winter have you tryed to do with a SCP is a command? it's more faster than SFTP. Or can you put all files in a zip to be faster?

@francisco unfortunately this is part of an application that reads files on a client's server not ours, and we monitor for changes. The files get pulled down locally and processed into our system so we don't touch their raw data. I have been able to successfully transfer via SCP and FileZilla outside of the application, so I'm pretty sure it's something related to the package or PHP?

The server is sending back a SSH_MSG_EXT_INFO message (type 7) and the Net SSH2 code does not support handling or ignoring this message type. Unfortunately I can't provide any hints on why it might be sending that message type back or how to stop if (if that's even possible). There might be a connection setting on the client side to disable it, maybe not. At least it has nothing to do with your code, but might be an "issue" with that SFTP server sending unsolicited ext-info packets back to the client (PHP Net SSH2) which doesn't support them.
